# Validation of input elements haing name as array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have textbox and upload file like:

```
<input type="text" id = "contract_copy_text[]" name="contract_copy_text[]" value="" maxlength="50"/>
<input type="file" name="contract_copy_pdf[]" id="contract_copy_pdf[]" accept="application/pdf" />
```

I am not able to validate it.

I have tried :

```
var contract_copy_text = $('#contract_copy_text[]').val(); // document.getElementById('contract_copy_text').value;
    var contract_copy_pdf = $('#contract_copy_pdf[]').val(); // document.getElementById('contract_copy_pdf').value;

    if (contract_copy_text == "") {
        alert("insert contract copy title for file");
        $('#err_lbl_contract_copy_text').html('insert contract copy title for file');
        return false;
    }

    if (contract_copy_pdf == "") {
        alert("Please select contract copy pdf file for upload");
        $('#err_lbl_contract_copy_pdf').html('Please select contract copy pdf file for upload');
        return false;
    }
```

But that doesn't work.

Please note: These fields are dynamically generated as required(on click).
Can anyone tell me what mistake I am making.

UPDATE:

Please see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/salunkheganesh07/fve8sbut/)

Comment: "But that doesn't work" doesnt work how? what happends? why do you have `[]` in your element id's? you have `return`'s in your code, where is the parent function and when are you calling it?

Comment: @atmd . Please see the fiddle

Comment: "haing name as array" — The name isn't an array. It just has `[]` in the name. PHP will give this special meaning and put the data from it into an array, but as far as HTML is concerned `[]` isn't anything special (as far as CSS is concerned, it is special in a selector so see Andrea's answer). The easier solution is to just change your IDs, there is no need for them to follow PHP's naming convention. Don't put `[]` in them and your life will be easier.

Comment: @Quentin Thank you. But I am uploading/inserting those field values and files in database. So using [ ] in name

Comment: @Ganesh — So what? Leave the name alone. You are putting `[]` in the ID as well and using an ID selector in the jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the way you wrote the jQuery selectors here:

```
var contract_copy_text = $('#contract_copy_text[]').val();
var contract_copy_pdf = $('#contract_copy_pdf[]').val();
```

You must escape the `[` and `]` characters (using `\\`) because [they have special meaning inside the selector expression](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/):

```
var contract_copy_text = $('#contract_copy_text\\[\\]').val();
var contract_copy_pdf = $('#contract_copy_pdf\\[\\]').val();
```

Source https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ :

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \.

Comment: Specifically you must escape the `[` and `]` with ``\`` in the selector and then escape the ``\`` with another ``\`` in the string literal that you put the selector in.

Answer (score -1):

Could you not access it via starts with Javascript selector

Id

```
$( "input[id^='contract_copy_text']" )
```

Or name

```
$( "input[name^='contract_copy_text']" )
```

Which will be an array

and then iterate through using .each

```
$( "input[id^='contract_copy_text']" ).each(function( index ) {
  var x = $( this ).val();
});
```